# How to add a class for texts between specific characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing my own blog using Blogger. I want to mark some prominent words. For example, when I write `*Red*` in an editor. It should automatically add a `key` class and wrap it with the span tag. So, the final result should be as following:

```
<span class="key">Red</span>
```

Now, I am trying to write a JQuery script but it still doesn't work properly.

```
$markText = $('span').filter(function(){
$t = $(this).text();
return $t.charAt(0) === "*" && $t.charAt(4) === "*"}).each(function() {
    $s1 = $t.slice(1,4);
    $s2 = $t.slice(5);
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="key">' + $s1+ '</span>' + '<span>'+$s2+'</span>');
});
```

Please see the demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNydF/2/)

Comment: have you tried to get just the result of filter, to make sure if it can find your span with *Red* in it?

Comment: @MehranHatami yes, It found the Red span. However, the result is quite strange and doesn't work in any other cases. So, what I want is to make it work in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be fixed by what RaymondM has suggested, but you could try something like this as well:

```
$markText = $('span').each(function (i, e) {
    $e = $(e);
    while ($(e).text().indexOf('*') != -1) {
        $e.html($e.html().replace('*', '<span class="key">').replace('*', '</span>'));
    }
});
```

This makes use of the fact that the `replace` method only modifies the first occurrence of the target string.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/aNydF/5/)

Comment: Thanks for you response. How it can get only the first occurrence? Does the while loop mean to replace all the asterisks found?

Comment: @LVarayut Umm, let me try to explain it properly this time. The `replace` method only replaces the first occurrence, that means  `'123123123123'.replace('2','5')` would give '153123123123'. So I have used two `replace` calls in each iteration of the while loop (the first to open the span tag, the second to close it). Each iteration would work on *one pair* of asterisks and wrap the inner content into a new span tag, and the loop will keep doing that until all such pairs have been found. See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/aNydF/5/), this works for multiple words as well.

Answer (score 0):

The *$t* in side the *each* function should be replaced by *$(this).text()*

```
$markText = $('span').filter(function(){
$t = $(this).text();
return $t.charAt(0) === "*" && $t.charAt(4) === "*"}).each(function() {
    $s1 = $(this).text().slice(1,4);
    $s2 = $(this).text().slice(5);
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="key">' + $s1+ '</span>' + '<span>'+$s2+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more details why it could make different result?